# Enabling session affinity on load balancer without clustering in websphere

Tags: websphere, load-balancing, websphere-7, session-affinity

We have a requirement to loadbalance 2 standalone WAS7 base version JVMs in two separate hosts. Both the JVMs will be served by a single IHS web server.  We are not creating any cluster. In addition to configuring a unique HTTP session clone ID for each JVM as below:

Navigate to :

```
Servers > Application servers > server_name > Container Settings > 
Web Container Settings > Web container > Additional Properties > Custom Properties > Click New
```

i)In the `Name` field, enter `HttpSessionCloneId`.

ii)In the `Value` field, enter a unique value for the server. The unique value must be 8 - 9 alphanumeric characters; for example, ``

Do we need to make any other configuration changes for enabling session affinity in WAS or IHS side?

Answer (score 2):

Go through this page - [Configuring simple load balancing across multiple application server profiles](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/twsv_configsimplelb.html?lang=en). It describes in detail all the steps you have to do.

In summary:

- Configure cloneIDs
- Generate plugin files for each
- Merge plugins
- Copy merged plugin to IHS

You can also configure session persistence, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks Gas . Is session affinity and session persistence same thing ? How are they different ? Little confused here ..

Comment: No, session affinity means that IHS with plugin will route to the same server if available, if not to other that serves that application (but session data is lost in case of switching to different server). Session persistence means that session data is replicated among participating servers, either via database, memory to memory replication or WebSphere Extreme Scale caching. For simple load balancing you can only use database for sharing sessions. In that case if one server fails, the other will pickup session in the same state. Hope it is more clear now ;-)

Comment: @BlueSaturn You can accept/upvote answer, if you found it useful.

Comment: Hi Gas ,I tried twice or thrice to upvote the answer but seems it will reflect only after I gain 15 reputation points :(